# LinuxのモジュールとしてのSELinuxとAndroidに実装されているSELinuxの違いとは？

Tags: android, security

Android Lollipop以降SELinuxが標準で有効になったと認識しています.

モバイルへのSElinuxの適用ということで、なにか既存のSELinuxと異なる点
などは存在するのでしょうか？

Comment: `既存のSELinux`とは何を指してますか？ KitKatとLolipopの比較という意味でしょうか。

Comment: モバイルの対ですので、サーバーサイドではないでしょうか（邪魔なので無効化する印象しかないですが…）。なお、SELinuxが標準動作するようになったバージョンは4.3だと思います（参考：[Security-Enhanced Linux in Android](https://source.android.com/security/selinux/)）。

Comment: サーバーサイドとモバイルでの話です.
例えば実装の面とかですね...